# Проксирование запросов в WebpackDevServer

Tags: javascript, proxy, webpack, webpack-dev-server

Пытаюсь настроить proxy для связки webpack-dev-server и rails. 
Настроил rails, по адресу http://192.168.1.223:3000/. Пытаюсь настроить прокси на клиенте

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    index: [
      "./src/init"
    ],
  },
  output: {
    publicPath: "/",
    path: __dirname + "/public/",
    filename: "[name].js"
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /(node_modules)/,
      loaders: ["react-hot", "babel"]
    }]
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: "./public",
    hot: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    proxy: {
      "/api": {
        target: "http://192.168.1.223:3000/",
        pathRewrite: {
          "^/api": ""
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Запускаю dev-server на порту 8080. Открываю http://localhost:8080/api, вижу что все запросы на Rails прилетают в виде http://192.168.1.223:3000/api/request хотя я прошу присылать запросы на http://192.168.1.223:3000/request как мне это исправить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело было в том что версия webpack-dev-server была < 1.15.0